# request.form elements is null

Tags: html, asp.net, forms

I have a simple asp.net webform, upon posting it to another page, the `request.form` collection seems to be empty. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Form:**

```
<form runat="server" id="myform" action="submitForm.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-6" name="myName"/> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

On my **submitForm.aspx** page load, I have:

```
  Response.Write(Request.Form["myName"].ToString());
```

This just creates a null reference exception.

I don't have the runat server element on my textboxes and I don't want them. Although, in Google Developer Tools, I can see that `myName` is posted with the correct value. Any ideas?

Comment: For `Request.Form[""]` to work your control should be a server side control, so you should have `runat="server"` attribute on your control.

Comment: i am not sure thats the case..anyways..i added runat="server" and it still didnt work.

Comment: Try `Request.Form("myName")`

Comment: when i try that   Error : Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.Form' cannot be used like a method

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned your control should be a server side control if you want to retrieve the value using `HttpRequest` object so first thing you should do is to add `runat="server"` tag.

Secondly since its a server side control now, ASP.NET uses naming convention for server side controls which will change your `name` attribute(you can verify this by checking the source of page). To render the `name` attribute properly you need to specify the `id` attribute of your control this wil automatically add the name attribute for you.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-6" id="myName" runat="server" />
```

Will be rendered as:-

```
 <input name="myName" type="text" id="myName" class="form-control col-xs-6" />
```

Now, your code will work as expected:-

```
Request.Form["myName"]
```

**Edit:**

Since you are using master page, `ASP.NET` will not only modify the `id` but also the `name` attribute. If you are using `ASP.NET 4` you can use `clientidmode` to make the `id` static:-

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-6" id="myName" runat="server" 
clientidmode="Static" />
```

But still it's not possible to change the `name` attribute so you need to do that Javascript something like this:-

```
$(function () {
      $("#myName").attr("name", "myName");
});
```

After this it should work for you.

Comment: I have the same code as you had mentioned. For some reason i am still getting null reference exception. I am using master page so the name attribute got renamed. I am using the renamed version to on the other page, but its still not working. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: i am just going to use code-behind to capture the values..(Request.Form works fine then without any runat="server") I will process in the code behind and then redirect to the second page. ! I am still not sure why its not working when posting to a different page.

Comment: @cableload - Not satisfied with the answer? ;)